# VideoPlayer keeps building under parents

Tags: flutter

my VideoPlayer widget  (im using it for web), keeps building under the color of the parent container, i honestly dont know what to do, i have tried multiple things but nothing, is not a stack issue since the child of the video player is in the correct layer, is just the VideoPlayer that is being built on the back of everything.

```
import 'package:ThePack/domain/screen_utils.dart';
import 'package:ThePack/presentation/pages/home_screen/sections/widgets/play_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoPlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String video;
  double margin, width, height, scrollbarWidth;
   VideoPlayerWidget({required this.video,
    this.height = 44,
    this.width = 40,
    this.margin = 5,
    this.scrollbarWidth = 30
   });
  @override
  _VideoPlayerWidgetState createState() => _VideoPlayerWidgetState();
}

class _VideoPlayerWidgetState extends State<VideoPlayerWidget> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  bool _isPlaying = false;
  double _progressValue = 0.0;
  double count = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Replace 'path/to/local/video.mp4' with the actual path to your video file
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(widget.video);

    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.value.position >= _controller.value.duration) {
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = false;
        });
      } else if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
        setState(() {
          _progressValue =
              _controller.value.position.inMilliseconds.toDouble() /
                  _controller.value.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    String minutes = duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String seconds = duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return '$minutes:$seconds';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              key: ValueKey(count),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, widget.margin)),
              height: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, widget.height),
              width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, widget.width),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                // color: Color(0xff6C6666),
),
              child: 
              _controller.value.isInitialized?
              VideoPlayer(_controller)
              :SizedBox()
            ),

            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, widget.margin)),
              height: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, widget.height),
              width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, widget.width),
              decoration: _boxDecorationOpacity(),
              child: 
              !_isPlaying?
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: ()=> _playPause(),
                  icon: PlayButton())

              :InkWell(
                focusColor: Colors.transparent,
               highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                onTap: () => _playPause()
              
            )),
          ]),

            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, widget.margin),top: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, 2)),
              width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, widget.width),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
              
                   SizedBox(
                    width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, widget.scrollbarWidth),
                    child: Slider(
                      value: _progressValue,
                      onChanged: (value) =>  _navigationProgressBar(value),     
                      activeColor: Color(0xFFFF7373),
                      inactiveColor: Color(0xFFFF7373).withAlpha(100),
                    )),

                  const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                  
                   Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [

                      Text(
                        formatDuration(_controller.value.position),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.red)),

                      Text(
                        "  -  ",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.red)),

                      Text(
                        formatDuration(_controller.value.duration),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.red)),

                    ]),
                ],
              ),
            )
      ],
    );
  }

  void _navigationProgressBar(double value) {
    return setState(() {
                        final Duration newPosition = Duration(
                          milliseconds:
                              (value * _controller.value.duration.inMilliseconds)
                                  .round(),
                        );
                        _controller.seekTo(newPosition);
                      });
  }

  void _playPause() {
    return setState(() {
                        if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                          _controller.pause();
                          _isPlaying = false;
                        } else {
                          _controller.play();
                          _isPlaying = true;
                        }
                      });
  }

   BoxDecoration _boxDecorationOpacity() {
    return BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: 
                !_isPlaying?
                Color.fromARGB(96, 0, 0, 0)
                :Colors.transparent);
  }
}
```

I have tried adding a delay, making a check for it to be initialized and forcing it to rebuild, i must be doing something since i don't have experience with statefuls.

Answer (score 1):

I think the backgroundBlendMode propertry of Box Decoration can fix your issue. 
In the decoration property of the first Container in the stack which which contains Video player, try replacing the following

```
  decoration: BoxDecoration(  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                // color: Color(0xff6C6666),),
```

with

```
  decoration: BoxDecoration(  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.clear,
                // color: Color(0xff6C6666),),
```

You can then adjust margin/border/padding due to side effects of the
above code.
Hope it helps.
Thanks :)